# Django. Ajax. Не полностью заполненная форма <form> не дает перейти на новую страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Друзья, у меня в django-проекте в html-шаблоне есть форма

`<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_act' %}">`

Внутри этой формы лежат 4 селекта `<select>`. В селекты инфа подгружается  динамически:

```
{% for f in form_all %}
    <option value="{{ f.id }}">{{ f.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

В конце данной формы есть кнопка

```
<button type="submit" id="send-button">Кнопочка</button>
```

Выбранные данные из этой формы передаются на сервер с помощью javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send-button").click(function() {
        var fdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "my_url",
            type: "POST",
            data: fdata,
            success : function(json) {
                alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");
            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

На основе выбранных данных, django выдаёт новую страничку по новому урлу.

**Проблема:** Переход на новую страничку работает только тогда, когда во всех 4 селектах что-то выбрано. То есть выберу я данные в 3 из 4 селектов - js мне выдаст сообщение *"Successfully sent the URL to Django"*, но на новую страничку не перейдёт. Выберу что-то во всех 4 селектах - переходит.

**Внимание, вопрос:** сталкивались вы с такой или подобной ситуацией и где может быть скрыта проблема?

*функция во `views.py` самая обычная из разряда:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    return render(request, 'apppp/new_page.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче, пацаны и девчонки, такой дибилизм ))) День отмучиться, перерыть весь проект, чтобы найти простейший и тривиальный ответ.

**Ответ**: волшебное слово `novalidate` в теге `<form>`.

Друзья, если у вас, как и у меня, в проекте есть форма с несколькими объектами/выбиралками/селектами/инпутами внутри и нет значения по умолчанию в этих объектах, не забывайте ставить данный параметр. Таким образом форма, будучи не(недо)заполненной, прекрасно отсылается на сервер.

```
<form novalidate id="myForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_act' %}">
```